# LibGDX: Adding window to stage overrides all input

Tags: input, libgdx, window, scene2d

**Problem:** I am trying to add a window to my game that does not override all input. I want to be able to move the player with keyboard input while a window is open.

**What I tried:**

- I added the stage and the player input control handler in an InputMultiplexer but it seems that Scene2D stage's completely ignore all input if it doesn't affect the most recently added window.
- I tried to get keyboard input from Window and pass it on to my player input handler. Was unable to find any input processor in Window class.
- Modified the precedence of player input handler to top of input multiplexer, still gets ignored.

**Question:**
Is there a way to override this functionality? I must be missing something. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of describing your code you could show us the code.

Comment: https://github.com/vedi0boy/ArchipeloClient  Here is my git repo. The code in question is within `core/src/.../screens/gamescreen/chatwindow.java` (Window) and `core/src/.../screens/gamesscreen.java` (Screen for game) and `core/src/.../tools/controlsmanager.java` (Player controls input manager).

Comment: When you say "all" input, do you literally mean all types of input, or just the keyboard? You set your ChatWindow to get the stage's keyboard focus. I don't see why it would claim any other types of input if you didn't set it to `isModal`.

Comment: It seems as though touch input works. I added code to unfocus the keyboard if the user touches outside the window but it still doesn't see keyboard input. Also, what is `isModal`?